# Generate a new string through two others common strings

Tags: python, string, list

Generate a new string through two others common strings but i am having a problem in my own Python code.
The code is:

```
string1 = "doesnt matter"
string2 = "doesnt matter too"
listt = []
n = 0
while n < len(string1) or len(string2):
    if string1[n] in string2:
        listt.append(string1[n])
    n += 1
```

When i run the code, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#121>", line 2, in <module>
    if string1[n] in string2:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I don't know why string index is out of range, if the `n = 0` and the string is greater than 0.

Thanks in advance,

@viddhart4d8

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your example, it doesn't make sense as is and thus hard to debug for you.

Comment: What do you mean with "common strings"? Simply take all characters from the first string that are also in the second string? Please post an example of your input and expected output...

Comment: I tried to use the tag code here in but i think is not working. All indentation is okay.

Comment: `n < len(string1) or len(string2)` does not what you think it does

Comment: change `n < len(string1) or len(string2)` to `n < len(string1) or n < len(string2)`

Comment: I mean generate a  third string with the common letters in the string1 and string2.

Comment: Common letters at the same position? Or just all common letters? What would be the result for "abcabc" and "abcdab"?

Comment: Thanks yentup. Works now. T Thanks all you guys too.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two problems here.

First, as Mike pointed out, `n < len(string1) or len(string2)` is equivalent to `(n < len(string)) or len(string2)`. In other words, as long as `len(string2)` is not zero, this will *always* be true. To fix this, change it to `n < len(string1) or n < len(string2)`.

But when you fix that, nothing will change; you'll still get an `IndexError`. The problem here is that, not only did you implement your logic incorrectly, the logic is wrong in the first place. `len(string1)` is 13, and `len(string2)` is 17. So, what happens when `n` is 13? Well, `n < 13 or n < 17` is obviously true, so you're still going to hit that next line and try to do `string1[n]`.

You could change the `or` to an `and` to fix that.

But really, it's better to write code that's harder to get wrong in the first place.

First, you can do this:

```
while n < min(len(string1), len(string2)):
```

Second, whenever you write a loop that starts with `n = 0`, does a `while` loop over `n < <something>`, and does an `n += 1`, you can, and should, rewrite it as a `for` loop over a range:

```
for n in range(min(len(string1), len(string2))):
```

Meanwhile, if you think about it, I don't think you want to stop early if `string2` is shorter than `string1`. So really, what you want is:

```
for n in range(len(string1)):
```

And whenever you find yourself looping over `range(len(<something>))` and then doing `<something[n]>` inside the loop, you really just want to loop over `<something>` directly:

```
for ch in string1:
```

Let's put this together:

```
string1 = "doesnt matter"
string2 = "doesnt matter too"
listt = []
for ch in string1:
    if ch in string2:
        listt.append(ch)
```

This is a lot more readable—and, more importantly for a novice, it's much harder to get anything wrong. Even experienced programmers often use `<` when they should have used `<=`, or get the parentheses wrong in a complex `if` statement, etc. But if you don't have to write that logic in the first place, you can't make those mistakes.

In fact, you can take this even further, because this pattern is exactly what a list comprehension does (or, alternatively, the `filter` function), so:

```
string1 = "doesnt matter"
string2 = "doesnt matter too"
listt = [ch for ch in string1 if ch in string2]
```

But at this point, we're not removing opportunities for error.

Comment: +1 for the solution "harder to get wrong", it's a good thought

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
string1 = "doesnt matter"
string2 = "doesnt matter too"
listt = [x for x in string1 if x in string2]
```

The code above is simpler and avoids the need to deal with indexes, etc. while manually looping over the input string - in fact, this is the preferred way to solve the problem in Python.

Or if you want to explicitly use a loop, here's a fixed version of your code - in particular, notice that the condition only needs to use `len(string1)`, there's no need to ask for `string2`'s length:

```
listt = []
n = 0
while n < len(string1):
    if string1[n] in string2:
        listt.append(string1[n])
    n += 1
```

The previous loop can be written more idiomatically like this, noticing that there's no need to use an index for iterating over a list - that's what [for loops](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) were made for:

```
for x in string1:
    if x in string2:
        listt.append(x)
```

The three solutions are equivalent, and the result is now as expected:

```
listt
=> ['d', 'o', 'e', 's', 'n', 't', ' ', 'm', 'a', 't', 't', 'e', 'r']
```

Comment: The point about avoiding explicit indices, loops, etc. is very important, and nicely written. But all the details are wrong. There's no list comprehension here; that's a generator expression. Also, since it returns a string instead of a list, it's not equivalent.

Comment: @abarnert you're absolutely right. why the heck did I put that `join()` in there?. It's fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted this instead:

```
while n < len(string1) or n < len(string2):
```

What you're doing is boiling down to:

```
while (n < len(string1)) or (len(string2))
```

Your statement is two things OR'd together, meaning if either one is true then the whole condition is true. In this case `len(string2)` is no-0 so it's "true" regardless of what `n` is doing.

And, as abarnert pointed out, an "or" is not the correct check anyway. Length of 13 OR length of 17 will still overflow a length of 13 (because the < 17 check will keep you going just like the `len(string2)` keeps you going).

I feel the quickest solution will simply be replace the `or` with an `and`.

```
while (n < len(string1)) and (n < len(string2))
```

This will now stop running once `n` is `>=` the length of either string (in this case the shorter 13)

Comment: Also known as the most common beginner programmer's logic error ever, in just about any language.

Comment: This isn't actually going to fix the problem. When `n==14`, it will still be true that `n < len(string1) or n < len(string2)`, so you'll still do `string1[n]`, and get the same `IndexError`.

Comment: @abarnert - Yes, quite right. I saw that when I first posted and totally forgot to fix it in my answer. Corrected now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `n < len(string1) or len(string2)` to:

```
n < len(string1) or n < len(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
string1 = "doesnt matter"
string2 = "doesnt matter too"
listt = []
n = 0
while n<len(string1) and n<len(string2):
    if string1[n] in string2:
        listt.append(string1[n])
    n += 1
```

Note the difference between:

```
while n<len(string1) and n<len(string2):
                     ^^^ ^^
```

vs what you have of:

```
while n<len(string1) or len(string2):
                     ^^
```

If you want use `or` you need to negate the whole conjugate to obtain:

```
while not(n>=len(string1) or n>=len(string2)):
```

Which does not read as easily I think. You can also use a Python looking form like this:

```
while all(n<len(s) for s in (string1,string2)):
```

Which work for any number of strings in an equally readable manner.

Answer (score -2):

string1 is 4 characters (upperbound 3)
string2 is 6 characters (upperbound 5)

Even when you fix the loop condition there are still issues
Your loop condition is while n < (4 or 6)

This would mean that this loops while n<6. At some point n will be 4,5 and 6 all of which are out of the bounds index for string1[n]. Im not sure what youre trying to achieve in terms of output. Maybe you are extracting common characters?
C#

```
string s1="xz";
string s2="xyz";
string combined="";

//loop through s1 letter by letter
for (int i=0; i<len(s1); i++){
     s1[i] represents x when i=0

     //loop through s2
     for (int j=0; j<len(s2); j++){
          //if s1[i] (x when i=0) s2[j] (s2[0]=x s2[1]=y s2[2]=z)

          //if they are equal append them to a string named combined and move to the next s1[i] iteration
          if (s1[i]==s2[j]){
            combined+=s1[i];
            break;
          }
     }
}
```

combined should now be xz

Comment: This is a python question, please don't answer with a solution in c#. the python equivalent to your mass of code would be `''.join(x for x in s1 if x in s2)`

Comment: A programming concept is a programming concept. Programming is not language specific. Im assuming python has loops and arrays, does it let you access array indexes that are o ut of bounds? I was just illustrating that he was going out of the index bounds. Then I gave an example in c#, which he could convert to python equivalents. (Have you never used a solution in a different language? and applied the concept to the language you were using?)

Comment: @ScottMoniz: Your answer will only be helpful to the OP if he can read C# (or at least a similar-enough language like Java or C++), which is an unwarranted assumption. Also, while of course Python has loops and arrays, there are very significant differences. Python doesn't have C-style `for` loops; only `for…in` loops. If you don't know how to rewrite your code using `for…in` in C#, you can't expect a Python programmer to know how to translate your C-style loop. Meanwhile, many things that would throw an indexing exception in C#, like `a[-1]`, are valid and meaningful in Python.